# How can we reuse configured AMI in the same template with the same userdata configs

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, user-data, aws-cloudformation

I have created instance using cloudformation template, configured it with userdata configuration and powershell dsc. I have created AMI for this instance so that next time it speeds up my stack creation.

Now how can i use the this AMI in that same template so it bypass all the configurations & installation done on instance and directly sends success signal to waithandler.

I am trying this in my template but it is failing.

Thanks in Advance,
Lokesh Jangir

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a check in your user data to see if everything is already configured, and if it is, then you just stop and send the notification instead of setting it back up again.

Ultimately, it sounds like it'd be easier to have two templates - one to create the AMI, and one to re-use it in other settings. The second template could take the AMI ID as a parameter so that it is more flexible and can be used with different AMIs as you create them.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** To use your AMI id in the cloudformation template, start with **adding a parameter**, so that you can easily change it:

`

```
"Parameters": {
...
"amiId": {
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "ami-073bb070",
  "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*",
  "Description": "Only [a-zA-Z0-9\\-]* allowed."
},
...
}
```

**2.** Use that param in a **LaunchConfig**:

`

```
  "aLaunchConfig": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": { "Ref" : "amiId" },
    ...
```

**3.** or use it **directly in an EC2 instance**:

`

```
"someEC2": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": { "Ref" : "amiId" },
```